# Is anyone running Azure functions locally from either OSX or MacOS Sierra?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm working in MacOS Sierra and am trying to determine how to execute my functions, triggers, etc. without using the Azure Portal UI or the need for an installation of Windows. I'm working with Node. Could someone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

[Azure Functions CLI](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/12/01/running-azure-functions-locally-with-the-cli/) has support for running functions locally but this is not supported on MacOS yet. We do have a tracking item to [make CLI cross plat](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/13)

Answer (score 0):

Starting Sep 25, 2017 it's now possible to run them on macOS and Linux: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/09/25/develop-azure-functions-on-any-platform/